# При обновлении состояния в React получаю ошибку: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, объекты, компоненты

Почему у меня уходит в бесконечный цикл? Что я делаю не так?
Известны поля объекта, они не изменяются и идет сравнение именно по ним.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   const { obj, arrHistory } = this.state;
   if (!this.isEquals(obj, prevProps.obj)) {
     let newArr = arrHistory;
     newArr.push(obj);
     this.setState({
       arrHistory: newArr,
       obj: obj
     })
   }
 }

 isEquals = (obj1, obj2) => {
   return (obj1.name === obj2.name ||
       obj1.arr.join() === obj2.arr.join() ||
       obj1.x === obj2.x ||
       obj1.y === obj2.y);
 }
```

Comment: можете скинуть весь код? например в песочнице или другим способом

Comment: Вы в componentDidUpdate меняете State, это вызывает ре редеринг компоненты.  После рендера опять запускается componentDidUpdate, и снова меняет State, это вызывает ре редеринг...  Сделайе выход из этого цикла условием отмены изменения State.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло изменение в функции `isEquals` `||` (или) на `&&` (и) и всё заработало как надо!